# Merge an Audio file with a Video file in Flutter without losing the original audio of the video

Tags: flutter

i merged video with auto with this command

```
 final command = "-i file.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -c:v copy -c:a aac -b:a 128k -shortest video.mp4 "
 final return0 = await FFmpegKit.execute(command);
```

(https://pub.dev/packages/ffmpeg_kit_flutter)
but the video after merging lost the sound of the video only the music
how can i (Merge an Audio file with a Video file in Flutter without losing the original audio of the video)

Merge an Audio file with a Video file in Flutter without losing the original audio of the video